# OpenVPN connection breaks time to time: TLS Error: local/remote TLS keys are out of sync

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, udp

We have our own VPN in my workplace. Everyone has its own key. However I am the only one who works on linux, the rest use either Macs or Windows machines. Unfortunately I have not found any good client application for OpenVPN so I am launching it from terminal:

```
sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn
```

The problem is that sometimes connection breaks with the following error:

```
TLS Error: local/remote TLS keys are out of sync: [AF_INET]
```

and I need to restart it 15-20 times until succesful reconnection occurs. Here is a content of `client.ovpn` config file.

```
dev tun
proto udp
remote /*ip-address of server here*/ 1194
client
resolv-retry infinite
ca "ca.crt"
cert "mycrt.crt"
key "mykey.key"
tls-auth "ta.key" 1
remote-cert-tls server
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
status-version 3
tls-timeout 120
tun-mtu 1500
fragment 1300
mssfix 1300
```

Comment: Have you try to sync the time of your machine?

Comment: @RomeoNinov, no I have not. I have set automatic date-time. The vpn server is located in different place.

Comment: Install on your machine `ntp` and run it. Because this can be the reason of your problem

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this issue by setting the timezone to be the same as where my VPN that I was using was located.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Setting the same time zone is not required. (For instance, I am using it having different time zones here and there.) All you need to do is to make both you and the server agree on which **UTC** time is currently, as OpenVPN uses UTC for time comparisons. The easiest way to do this is set up time synchronization using NTP, as suggested in comments.